# How to Invert String Typed Data into Non-String Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
data= pd.read_csv("/Users/zachary/Desktop/banking.csv")
data = data.dropna()
features = list(data.columns)
data.education.unique()
```

`print(features)` returns

> ['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan',
>   'contact', 'month', 'day_of_week', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays',
>   'previous', 'poutcome', 'emp_var_rate', 'cons_price_idx',
>   'cons_conf_idx', 'euribor3m', 'nr_employed', 'y']

I have 21 features. and

`print(data.education.unique())` returns how many possible classes in features named `'education'`

I'd like to print every `data."feature_name".unique()` through loop.

but `feature[i]` returns `"string"` which cannot be looped in concatenated form, e.g.

```
for i in features:
    method = data. + features[i] + unique()
    print(method)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can I test it? What should the output look like?

Comment: the output should like 

[every classes of age: 0, 1, 2....]
[every classes of job: programmer, lawyer, ...]
...

Comment: oh for the dataset, you can refer to here :https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8

Answer (score 2):

you can access to a column like a dictionary, so just:

```
data= pd.read_csv("/Users/zachary/Desktop/banking.csv")
data = data.dropna()
features = list(data.columns)
for feature in features:
    print(data[feature].unique())
```

Comment: aha.. that's also possible. but anyidea we can change the string into just variable?

Comment: You mean loop over columns without index them?

Comment: exactly. I'd like to take out each element from the list, and take off " ", which means they are no more strings, then it makes the method like data.feature[i].unique() then this method just excuted and printed

Comment: In my answer there isn't " ", anyway another option is:
for key, value in features.iteritems():
    print(value.unique())

Comment: Are you asking how to use the dot (`.`) operator to access a column with a variable name? I do not think that is possible. `df["column_name"]` is equivalent to `df.column_name`. This solution does the same thing. Why do you need to do it the other way?

Comment: @pault This's a kind of example. I've been faced a lot with this kind of situation that I wanted to invert string into variable to make my development fast . So I had asked borrowing this simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You can using list map

```
list(map(set,data.values.T))
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more what map does, and what is the set?

Comment: @map, you can think map doing the for loop here, `df.values.T` return the list of list (ndarray), map is doing the set (unique value for list)for each of them and return it by its original structure (list of list)